# ESP32-CAM Arduino Upload Error: Invalid head of packet (0x61)

Tags: esp32, arduino-uno, robot

i am trying to build a robot car with arduino and esp32-cam but when i'm trying to upload the code through the arduino i get this:

```
A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP32: Invalid head of packet (0x61): Possible serial noise or corruption.
```

the compile goes smoothly and the problem happens at the upload.
i am connected to ESP32 WROVER MUDOLE, upload speed: 115200.
i checked connections, tried reset but nothing worked.

```
#include "esp_camera.h"
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <AsyncTCP.h>
#include <ESPAsyncWebServer.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

struct MOTOR_PINS
{
  int pinEn;  
  int pinIN1;
  int pinIN2;    
};

std::vector<MOTOR_PINS> motorPins = 
{
  {12, 13, 15},  //RIGHT_MOTOR Pins (EnA, IN1, IN2)
  {12, 14, 2},  //LEFT_MOTOR  Pins (EnB, IN3, IN4)
};
#define LIGHT_PIN 4

#define UP 1
#define DOWN 2
#define LEFT 3
#define RIGHT 4
#define STOP 0

#define RIGHT_MOTOR 0
#define LEFT_MOTOR 1

#define FORWARD 1
#define BACKWARD -1

const int PWMFreq = 1000; /* 1 KHz */
const int PWMResolution = 8;
const int PWMSpeedChannel = 2;
const int PWMLightChannel = 3;

//Camera related constants
#define PWDN_GPIO_NUM     32
#define RESET_GPIO_NUM    -1
#define XCLK_GPIO_NUM      0
#define SIOD_GPIO_NUM     26
#define SIOC_GPIO_NUM     27
#define Y9_GPIO_NUM       35
#define Y8_GPIO_NUM       34
#define Y7_GPIO_NUM       39
#define Y6_GPIO_NUM       36
#define Y5_GPIO_NUM       21
#define Y4_GPIO_NUM       19
#define Y3_GPIO_NUM       18
#define Y2_GPIO_NUM        5
#define VSYNC_GPIO_NUM    25
#define HREF_GPIO_NUM     23
#define PCLK_GPIO_NUM     22

const char* ssid     = "MyWiFiCar";
const char* password = "12345678";

AsyncWebServer server(80);
AsyncWebSocket wsCamera("/Camera");
AsyncWebSocket wsCarInput("/CarInput");
uint32_t cameraClientId = 0;

const char* htmlHomePage PROGMEM = R"HTMLHOMEPAGE(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <style>
    .arrows {
      font-size:40px;
      color:red;
    }
    td.button {
      background-color:black;
      border-radius:25%;
      box-shadow: 5px 5px #888888;
    }
    td.button:active {
      transform: translate(5px,5px);
      box-shadow: none; 
    }

    .noselect {
      -webkit-touch-callout: none; /* iOS Safari */
        -webkit-user-select: none; /* Safari */
         -khtml-user-select: none; /* Konqueror HTML */
           -moz-user-select: none; /* Firefox */
            -ms-user-select: none; /* Internet Explorer/Edge */
                user-select: none; /* Non-prefixed version, currently
                                      supported by Chrome and Opera */
    }

    .slidecontainer {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 15px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background: #d3d3d3;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }

    .slider:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  
    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: red;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background: red;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    </style>
  
  </head>
  <body class="noselect" align="center" style="background-color:white">
     
    <!--h2 style="color: teal;text-align:center;">Wi-Fi Camera &#128663; Control</h2-->
    
    <table id="mainTable" style="width:400px;margin:auto;table-layout:fixed" CELLSPACING=10>
      <tr>
        <img id="cameraImage" src="" style="width:400px;height:250px"></td>
      </tr> 
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="button" ontouchstart='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","1")' ontouchend='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","0")'><span class="arrows" >&#8679;</span></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="button" ontouchstart='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","3")' ontouchend='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","0")'><span class="arrows" >&#8678;</span></td>
        <td class="button"></td>    
        <td class="button" ontouchstart='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","4")' ontouchend='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","0")'><span class="arrows" >&#8680;</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td class="button" ontouchstart='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","2")' ontouchend='sendButtonInput("MoveCar","0")'><span class="arrows" >&#8681;</span></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr/><tr/>
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left"><b>Speed:</b></td>
        <td colspan=2>
         <div class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="150" class="slider" id="Speed" oninput='sendButtonInput("Speed",value)'>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>        
      <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left"><b>Light:</b></td>
        <td colspan=2>
          <div class="slidecontainer">
            <input type="range" min="0" max="255" value="0" class="slider" id="Light" oninput='sendButtonInput("Light",value)'>
          </div>
        </td>   
      </tr>
    </table>
  
    <script>
      var webSocketCameraUrl = "ws:\/\/" + window.location.hostname + "/Camera";
      var webSocketCarInputUrl = "ws:\/\/" + window.location.hostname + "/CarInput";      
      var websocketCamera;
      var websocketCarInput;
      
      function initCameraWebSocket() 
      {
        websocketCamera = new WebSocket(webSocketCameraUrl);
        websocketCamera.binaryType = 'blob';
        websocketCamera.onopen    = function(event){};
        websocketCamera.onclose   = function(event){setTimeout(initCameraWebSocket, 2000);};
        websocketCamera.onmessage = function(event)
        {
          var imageId = document.getElementById("cameraImage");
          imageId.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.data);
        };
      }
      
      function initCarInputWebSocket() 
      {
        websocketCarInput = new WebSocket(webSocketCarInputUrl);
        websocketCarInput.onopen    = function(event)
        {
          var speedButton = document.getElementById("Speed");
          sendButtonInput("Speed", speedButton.value);
          var lightButton = document.getElementById("Light");
          sendButtonInput("Light", lightButton.value);
        };
        websocketCarInput.onclose   = function(event){setTimeout(initCarInputWebSocket, 2000);};
        websocketCarInput.onmessage = function(event){};        
      }
      
      function initWebSocket() 
      {
        initCameraWebSocket ();
        initCarInputWebSocket();
      }

      function sendButtonInput(key, value) 
      {
        var data = key + "," + value;
        websocketCarInput.send(data);
      }
    
      window.onload = initWebSocket;
      document.getElementById("mainTable").addEventListener("touchend", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
      });      
    </script>
  </body>    
</html>
)HTMLHOMEPAGE";


void rotateMotor(int motorNumber, int motorDirection)
{
  if (motorDirection == FORWARD)
  {
    digitalWrite(motorPins[motorNumber].pinIN1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motorPins[motorNumber].pinIN2, LOW);    
  }
  else if (motorDirection == BACKWARD)
  {
    digitalWrite(motorPins[motorNumber].pinIN1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPins[motorNumber].pinIN2, HIGH);     
  }
  else
  {
    digitalWrite(motorPins[motorNumber].pinIN1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motorPins[motorNumber].pinIN2, LOW);       
  }
}

void moveCar(int inputValue)
{
  Serial.printf("Got value as %d\n", inputValue);  
  switch(inputValue)
  {

    case UP:
      rotateMotor(RIGHT_MOTOR, FORWARD);
      rotateMotor(LEFT_MOTOR, FORWARD);                  
      break;
  
    case DOWN:
      rotateMotor(RIGHT_MOTOR, BACKWARD);
      rotateMotor(LEFT_MOTOR, BACKWARD);  
      break;
  
    case LEFT:
      rotateMotor(RIGHT_MOTOR, FORWARD);
      rotateMotor(LEFT_MOTOR, BACKWARD);  
      break;
  
    case RIGHT:
      rotateMotor(RIGHT_MOTOR, BACKWARD);
      rotateMotor(LEFT_MOTOR, FORWARD); 
      break;
 
    case STOP:
      rotateMotor(RIGHT_MOTOR, STOP);
      rotateMotor(LEFT_MOTOR, STOP);    
      break;
  
    default:
      rotateMotor(RIGHT_MOTOR, STOP);
      rotateMotor(LEFT_MOTOR, STOP);    
      break;
  }
}

void handleRoot(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) 
{
  request->send_P(200, "text/html", htmlHomePage);
}

void handleNotFound(AsyncWebServerRequest *request) 
{
    request->send(404, "text/plain", "File Not Found");
}

void onCarInputWebSocketEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, 
                      AsyncWebSocketClient *client, 
                      AwsEventType type,
                      void *arg, 
                      uint8_t *data, 
                      size_t len) 
{                      
  switch (type) 
  {
    case WS_EVT_CONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u connected from %s\n", client->id(), client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DISCONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u disconnected\n", client->id());
      moveCar(0);
      ledcWrite(PWMLightChannel, 0);  
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DATA:
      AwsFrameInfo *info;
      info = (AwsFrameInfo*)arg;
      if (info->final && info->index == 0 && info->len == len && info->opcode == WS_TEXT) 
      {
        std::string myData = "";
        myData.assign((char *)data, len);
        std::istringstream ss(myData);
        std::string key, value;
        std::getline(ss, key, ',');
        std::getline(ss, value, ',');
        Serial.printf("Key [%s] Value[%s]\n", key.c_str(), value.c_str()); 
        int valueInt = atoi(value.c_str());     
        if (key == "MoveCar")
        {
          moveCar(valueInt);        
        }
        else if (key == "Speed")
        {
          ledcWrite(PWMSpeedChannel, valueInt);
        }
        else if (key == "Light")
        {
          ledcWrite(PWMLightChannel, valueInt);         
        }     
      }
      break;
    case WS_EVT_PONG:
    case WS_EVT_ERROR:
      break;
    default:
      break;  
  }
}

void onCameraWebSocketEvent(AsyncWebSocket *server, 
                      AsyncWebSocketClient *client, 
                      AwsEventType type,
                      void *arg, 
                      uint8_t *data, 
                      size_t len) 
{                      
  switch (type) 
  {
    case WS_EVT_CONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u connected from %s\n", client->id(), client->remoteIP().toString().c_str());
      cameraClientId = client->id();
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DISCONNECT:
      Serial.printf("WebSocket client #%u disconnected\n", client->id());
      cameraClientId = 0;
      break;
    case WS_EVT_DATA:
      break;
    case WS_EVT_PONG:
    case WS_EVT_ERROR:
      break;
    default:
      break;  
  }
}

void setupCamera()
{
  camera_config_t config;
  config.ledc_channel = LEDC_CHANNEL_0;
  config.ledc_timer = LEDC_TIMER_0;
  config.pin_d0 = Y2_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d1 = Y3_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d2 = Y4_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d3 = Y5_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d4 = Y6_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d5 = Y7_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d6 = Y8_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_d7 = Y9_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_xclk = XCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pclk = PCLK_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_vsync = VSYNC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_href = HREF_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_sda = SIOD_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_sscb_scl = SIOC_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_pwdn = PWDN_GPIO_NUM;
  config.pin_reset = RESET_GPIO_NUM;
  config.xclk_freq_hz = 20000000;
  config.pixel_format = PIXFORMAT_JPEG;
  
  config.frame_size = FRAMESIZE_VGA;
  config.jpeg_quality = 10;
  config.fb_count = 1;

  // camera init
  esp_err_t err = esp_camera_init(&config);
  if (err != ESP_OK) 
  {
    Serial.printf("Camera init failed with error 0x%x", err);
    return;
  }  

  if (psramFound())
  {
    heap_caps_malloc_extmem_enable(20000);  
    Serial.printf("PSRAM initialized. malloc to take memory from psram above this size");    
  }  
}

void sendCameraPicture()
{
  if (cameraClientId == 0)
  {
    return;
  }
  unsigned long  startTime1 = millis();
  //capture a frame
  camera_fb_t * fb = esp_camera_fb_get();
  if (!fb) 
  {
      Serial.println("Frame buffer could not be acquired");
      return;
  }

  unsigned long  startTime2 = millis();
  wsCamera.binary(cameraClientId, fb->buf, fb->len);
  esp_camera_fb_return(fb);
    
  //Wait for message to be delivered
  while (true)
  {
    AsyncWebSocketClient * clientPointer = wsCamera.client(cameraClientId);
    if (!clientPointer || !(clientPointer->queueIsFull()))
    {
      break;
    }
    delay(1);
  }
  
  unsigned long  startTime3 = millis();  
  Serial.printf("Time taken Total: %d|%d|%d\n",startTime3 - startTime1, startTime2 - startTime1, startTime3-startTime2 );
}

void setUpPinModes()
{
  //Set up PWM
  ledcSetup(PWMSpeedChannel, PWMFreq, PWMResolution);
  ledcSetup(PWMLightChannel, PWMFreq, PWMResolution);
      
  for (int i = 0; i < motorPins.size(); i++)
  {
    pinMode(motorPins[i].pinEn, OUTPUT);    
    pinMode(motorPins[i].pinIN1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorPins[i].pinIN2, OUTPUT);  

    /* Attach the PWM Channel to the motor enb Pin */
    ledcAttachPin(motorPins[i].pinEn, PWMSpeedChannel);
  }
  moveCar(STOP);

  pinMode(LIGHT_PIN, OUTPUT);    
  ledcAttachPin(LIGHT_PIN, PWMLightChannel);
}


void setup(void) 
{
  setUpPinModes();
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  IPAddress IP = WiFi.softAPIP();
  Serial.print("AP IP address: ");
  Serial.println(IP);

  server.on("/", HTTP_GET, handleRoot);
  server.onNotFound(handleNotFound);
      
  wsCamera.onEvent(onCameraWebSocketEvent);
  server.addHandler(&wsCamera);

  wsCarInput.onEvent(onCarInputWebSocketEvent);
  server.addHandler(&wsCarInput);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");

  setupCamera();
}


void loop() 
{
  wsCamera.cleanupClients(); 
  wsCarInput.cleanupClients(); 
  sendCameraPicture(); 
  Serial.printf("SPIRam Total heap %d, SPIRam Free Heap %d\n", ESP.getPsramSize(), ESP.getFreePsram());
}
```

Comment: is the esp32 in bootlotader mode? how is it connected to the computer? upload of Blink works?